# is it possible to achieve bevelled text and drop shadows using GDI in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi, graphicspath

I'm looking to expand my 'simple' photography events system to add the ability to add custom text to images we've shot. I technically have this aspect working using the existing picturebox control to display the image and a text box in which text can be entered and this will be added to the image being displayed.

However, being a photographer, I'd like the text to look a little nicer and as such am looking to emulate what I can do in Photoshop, i.e. bevel/emboss, add inner glows and drop shadows to this text but I'm struggling to find any references to this.

I may be simply limited by the fact I'm using winforms and this may have been achievable via WPF, but WPF wasn't about when I stopped being a programmer for a profession and as such stuck to technology I knew... I'm also far too far down the line in the system to re-write it all in WPF, so if its a limitation I'll just look at adding in pre-determined overlays rather than custom text which I know I can achieve.

The code I have so far is as follows and any tips on how to expand this to perform the bevel/emboss, glows etc would be much appreciated.

```
    public static Bitmap addTexttoImage(string imagename, string textnya)
    {

        float fontSize = 80;

        string imagepath = imagename;
        Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imagepath)));
        //read the image we pass
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imagepath);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        //this will centre align our text at the bottom of the image
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;

        //define a font to use.
        Font f = new Font("Impact", fontSize, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        //pen for outline - set width parameter
        Pen p = new Pen(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#77090C"), 8);
        p.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round; //prevent "spikes" at the path

        //this makes the gradient repeat for each text line
        Rectangle fr = new Rectangle(0, bmp.Height - f.Height, bmp.Width, f.Height);
        LinearGradientBrush b = new LinearGradientBrush(fr,
                                                        ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF6493"),
                                                        ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D00F14"),
                                                        90);

        //this will be the rectangle used to draw and auto-wrap the text.
        //basically = image size
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();

        gp.AddString(textnya, f.FontFamily, (int)FontStyle.Bold, fontSize, r, sf);

        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawPath(p, gp);
        g.FillPath(b, gp);

        //cleanup
        gp.Dispose();
        b.Dispose();
        b.Dispose();
        f.Dispose();
        sf.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
        return bmp;

    }
```

Comment: A really simple way is to write the text 3 times: once spot on in black and twice offset 1 pixel top left and bottom right in highlight and shadow colors.. Far from perfect but rather cheap.

Comment: cheers, I'll give that a go :)

Comment: Drop shadow is different from bevel. What's your requirement for this question? Also can you share a sample image about the requirement?